# Can an Android wearable device used with iOS, connected by BLE ? Is there any available SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os

I am working on a project that need to connect an android wearable device to an iPhone using smart bluetooth (BLE) to obtain some data from its sensors. Is it possible to connect an android wearable device with iPhone with BLE at all ? If there is, how to do that ? Are there any available SDK's ? And if it is not possible, is there a workaround to obtain sensor data to the iPhone. I am developing an iOS application in swift to receive and process this data.

Won't the different platforms restrict the connection ?

Comment: The Core Bluetooth framework on iOS provides connection to BLE devices.  You will need to look at that.  If your Android device implements standard GATT services and characteristics then you shouldn't have too much difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use CoreBluetooth native library for BLE in iOS there are Two main class CBPheripheralManger use to send or advertise data and another one is CBCentralManager for scanning or receiving data from bluetooth, And also i am sharing some github demo

https://github.com/JCGuidi/BLE-iOS-Swift-3.0